# Query para seleccionar ciertas columnas que cumplan la condicion

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
create table prof_est(id_est int, id_prof int, id_curso int, periodo varchar);
```

id_est corresponde al id del estudiante
id_prof es la identificación del profesor que esta dictando la materia
id_curso es la identeificacion del curso que esta tomando
y por ultimo 
periodo corresponde al año y semestre que  el estudiante esta tomando dicho curso con dicho profesor

la pregunta me pide generar un listado que muestra el id de los estudiantes que siempre han llevado más de 2 materias por periodo. La información de la tabla es la [siguiente](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L4EqT.jpg).

Esto significa que solo debería devolverme  el id de 203 porque solo este cumple con haber tomado mas de 2 materias en cada periodo (Solo aparece en un periodo),  el id de 201 no deberia aparecer debido a que tiene un periodo en el que no ha cumplido con la condición.

Tengo este query por el momento

```
select id_est, periodo, count(periodo) as materias from prof_est
group by id_est, periodo
```

la tabla que me lanza el query [esta aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uT4aT.jpg)
lo que muestra la tabla corresponde al id del estudiante, el periodo en el que ha estado, y el numero de materias que ha tomado en dicho periodo.

lo que busco obtener es solamente los id's de los estudiantes que en todos los periodos que han cursado, hayan tomado mas de 2 materias (que solo seria el caso de 203), como explique antes, 201 no se mostraría, puesto que hay un periodo en el que solo ha tomado 1 materia.

Comment: ¿La cantidad de materias es el número que hay después de la coma en la columna `periodo`? Sea así o no, todo apunta a que hay errores de diseño en tu tabla, sean lo que sean los valores como: `2018,1  ...` todo apunta a que eso a la larga te dará muchos problemas, pues tienes ahí una columna híbrida que no se sabe bien lo que es: controlar los posibles errores o hacer cálculos u ordenar en base a esa columna será harto complicado.

Comment: No, no corresponde a la cantidad de materias, es como decir 2018, 1er semestre, entonces lo que quiero ver es cuantas materias aparecen en ese periodo

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. Convendría que pusieras los datos de tu tabla aquí en la pregunta, no en una imagen aparte. Y que explicaras la columna que representa a las  materias en tu tabla y por qué criterios quieres filtrar los datos. Si lo que indica una materia es el id del profesor no es como dices, pues varios estudiantes tienen más de uno... Pero claro, todo lo que te pueda decir tengo que adivinarlo, porque no te has explicado con claridad en el planteamiento. Una explicación lo más clara posible es fundamental para que puedas recibir una respuesta mejor y más rápida.

Comment: Esta bien, me disculpo por la confusa explicacion. La columna posee la siguiente información:
id_est corresponde al id del estudiante
periodo corresponde al año y semestre que esta cursando (Por ejemplo: 2018,1 significa que esta en el semetre 1 del año 2018)
id_curso corresponde al curso que esta tomando

Ahora lo que yo necesito es  listar los id´s de los estudiantes que han tomado mas de 2 cursos en cada periodo que han estado.
Lo siento por no poder poner los datos de la tabla en la pregunta, pero solo puedo mostrarla en imagen aparte.

Comment: Al ejecutar el query que muestro en la pregunta lo que obtengo es el id del estudiante, el periodo en el que se encuentra, y el numero de cursos que ha tomado en dicho periodo, lo que necesito al final es filtrarlo mas para solo obtener el id de los estudiantes que en todos los periodos han tomado mas de dos materias

Comment: Por favor [edita la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/165980/edit) poniendo allí toda la información que pudiera ayudar a comprender mejor el problema, la estructura de la tabla y los resultados que quieres obtener. Nadie más que tú conoce el entorno, es necesario que lo expliques a los demás para que puedan entenderlo y darte una mejor solución y ayuda.

Comment: *... han tomado mas de dos **materias***... pero nunca explicas cuál es la columna que representa a las materias en la tabla. Se podría *adivinar*   que es la columna `id_prof`... Lo que quiero decir es que cuando plantees una pregunta expliques todo. Este es mi cuarto comentario y no termino de entender ni siquiera la estructura de tus tablas. Intuyo que lo que quieres se puede lograr con una consulta muy sencilla, pero si no te explicas bien poco se puede hacer.

Comment: Intenta probar con una consulta como esta: **`SELECT id_est, COUNT(periodo) materias FROM prof_est GROUP BY id_est, periodo HAVING COUNT(periodo) > 2`**

Comment: Debes ser mas claro en tu pregunta, es decir si dices siempre te refieres que el estudiante en cada periodo existente debe llevar mas de 2 o que se listen los que en algún periodo tienen mas de 2.

Comment: Cuando uso el count(periodo)>2 hay un problema, puesto que necesito que en todos los periodos se este cursando mas de 2 materias, como se ve en la imagen del query que utilizo, aparece 201 en cierto periodo en donde el numero de cursos tomados es menor a 3, por lo cual deberia excluirse

Comment: Me refiero a que en cada periodo existente debe llevar mas de 2 materias

Comment: Si quieres **más de dos materias**, como has dicho, significa `3, 4, 5...` en cambio, si quieres **dos o más materias**, entonces significa `2, 3, 4, 5...`. En ese caso tendrías que poner `HAVING COUNT(periodo) > 1`. Como has planteado las cosas se entiende que quieres lo primero, no lo segundo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En SQL haria algo como esto.

```
DECLARE @CANT_PERIODOS INT
DECLARE @TAB TABLE(IDE INT,CANT_CURSOS INT,PERIODO VARCHAR(20))
DECLARE @TAB2 TABLE(ID_E INT,CANT_PER INT)

SELECT @CANT_PERIODOS=COUNT(periodo) from prof_est
GROUP BY periodo    

INSERT INTO @TAB
SELECT id_est, count(id_curso), periodo from prof_est
GROUP BY id_est, periodo

INSERT INTO @TAB2
SELECT IDE,CANT(PERIODO) FROM @TAB
WHERE CANT_CURSOS>2
GROUP BY IDE

SELECT ID_E FROM @TAB2
WHERE CANT_PER = @CANT_PERIODOS
```

Comment: Tengo algo similar, el problema es que debo establecer como condicion que en TODOS los periodos haya tomado mas de 2 cursos, si uso el query de arriba, me devuelve el id de estudiantes que en al menos 1 curso han tomado mas de 2 materias, y eso no es lo que estoy buscando

Comment: ya modifique segun lo que indicaste.